# Jinja, Javascript and Google Maps Api, conflict

Tags: javascript, python, maps, jinja2

I'm trying to display a map using google api, but it's not showing.

```
<script type="text/javascript"    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAH35jXY2Yb5eApUzvZXuObiwFOpTC9xu0&sensor=true"> </script>
```

The key

```
{% if page == "Map"  %}
  <body bgcolor="#000000" onload="initialize()" >
    <div id="floater" style="color:#33ff33; width:100%;"> Cool Title Here </div>
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 60%; height:80%"></div>
  </body>
{% endif %}
```

Jinja

```
<script>
var map;
var markersArray = [];
var newMark;

function initialize() {
    var a = new google.maps.LatLng(40.731649,-73.923269);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 12    ,
        center: a,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
    };
    map =  new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
    {% for x in MessageList %}
    newMark = new google.maps.LatLng({{x[1]}},{{x[0]}});
    addMarker(newMark, "{{x[2]}}")  ;
    {% endfor %}
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({   content: "holding..."  });
    for (var i = 0; i < markersArray.length; i++) {
      var marker = markersArray[i];
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
    infowindow.setContent(this.user);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
    map.setCenter(this.getPosition());
  });    
    }
}
</script>
```

Javascript

I used this code before without Jinja on surrounding the body, and it worked for that.
Here's how it looked in my test page (doesn't show markers here, but they were functional)
[image]

Here's the current page I'm working with:
[image]

The console doesn't show any errors. Currently, the "floater" shows but the map doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Nvm. Turned out to be something as simple as the map_canvas cannot be within form brackets, only outside.